# binding virtualenv to project using setvirtualenvproject command doesn't work (windows)

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

I'm trying to bind my virtualenv to django project. So when I type the command  `workon my_project` it should cd to my django project.

```
(my_project) C:\User\User\Desktop\Project>
(my_project) C:\User\User\Desktop\Project>setvirtualenvproject
'setvirtualenvproject' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Why the command doesn't work?
Is there another way of binding virtualenv to my django project?

**RESOLVED**

I've managed to bind my virtualenv to my django project using this command

```
setprojectdir [path to the project folder]
```

Comment: Did not work for me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setvirtualenvproject` is a command from virtualenvwrapper. Do you have [virtualenvwrapper-win](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenvwrapper-win) installed?

Comment: I do. I created my virtualenv using mkvirtualenv command which is a virtualenvwrapper command. The environment was stored in my User\Envs\my_project.

Answer (score 9):

I've managed to bind my virtualenv to my django project using this command

```
setprojectdir [path to the project folder]
```

Comment: It seems virtualenvwrapper-win has some commands renamed. setvirtualenvproject -> setprojectdir; toggsitepackages -> toggleglobalsitepackages.